# lighttpd fastcgi with python and php on the same virtual host

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd

I have a python application running on the server, which should process any urls except `/wiki`. The `/wiki` url should show a php application.

My virtual host looks like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "domain.tld" {
        fastcgi.server = (
                "/django.fcgi" => (
                        "main" => (
                                "socket" => "/tmp/django.sock",
                                "check-local" => "disable",
                        )
                ),
                ".php" =>
                ((
                        "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
                        "socket" => "/tmp/php.socket",
                        "max-procs" => 1,
                        "bin-environment" => (
                                "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "4",
                                "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "10000"
                        ),
                        "bin-copy-environment" => (
                                "PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
                        ),
                        "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
                ))
        )

        url.rewrite-once = (
                "^(/wiki.*)$" => "/.../doku.php$1",
                "^(/.*)$" => "/django.fcgi$1",
        )
}
```

However, I am getting a 404 error for the php app, while the python app (django) is working. All paths are correct and the sockets exist. What is configured wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your paths really carefully? I think "/.../doku.php$1" is wrong, should be "/../doku.php$1" or "/../../doku.php$1". Otherwise everything should work.